# The constant function $f(z)=\infty$ from complex plane to the Riemann sphere.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis

How is $f(z)=\infty$ any different from $f(z)=c$ for some $c\in\mathbb{C}$ (if at all)?

I am asking this because an alternate definition on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function) of meromorphic functions excludes this case of the constant function. Also answer this generally irrespective of the function being meromorphic as I want to understand this function both analytically and topologically.

Comment: Analytically and topologically, it is no different than any other constant function. $f \equiv \infty$ is explicitly excluded because (one reason, for me the most compelling) that way the set of meromorphic functions on a (connected) Riemann surface is a field.

Comment: Maybe, since $f(z)=c$ and $f(z)=\infty$ are both holomorphic (on co-domain $\mathbb{\hat{C}}$) but one is included and the other excluded explicitly! What exactly stops it from being a field after adding this function, if you have verified rigorously?

Comment: $f \equiv \infty$ has neither a multiplicative nor an additive inverse. It's essentially the same reason why $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ isn't a field, while $\mathbb{C}$ is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ the Riemann sphere.
Let $F:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ be a holomorphic map between Riemann surfaces.

Fact $1$: if $F$ is not constant, then the preimage $F^{-1}(a)$ of any point $a\in\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is a discrete subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

> Proof: Let $x\in F^{-1}(a)$. $F$ is holomorphic $\implies$ there exists holomorphic charts $U$ containing $x$ and $V$ containing $a$ such that $U\xrightarrow{F} V$ is holomorphic. Then by complex analysis, either $x$ is an isolated point of $F^{-1}(a)$ or $F$ is constant locally. We therefore deduce $F^{-1}(a)=\{\text{isolated points}\}\cup U$ with $U$ being an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$. $U$ is therefore closed and open. Hence either $U=\emptyset$ and $F^{-1}(a)$ has only isolated points, or $U=\mathbb{C}$ and $F$ is constant.

Using this, one can show that, if $F$ is not constantly $\infty$, then the restriction of $F$ to $\mathbb{C}-F^{-1}(\infty)$ defines a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}-F^{-1}(\infty)$. Moreover, points of $F^{-1}(\infty)$ are poles of $F$ (i.e. there exists a Laurentz series).

The constant map $\infty$ cannot be a meromorphic function, for every point would be a pole.

On the other hand, it's true that there exists a biholomorphic map $\phi:\hat{\mathbb{C}}\rightarrow\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ such that $\phi(c)=\infty$ for every $c\in\mathbb{C}$. In this sense, $c$ and $\infty$ are not quite different.

Comment: 1. Isn't the fact true only for the compact Riemann surfaces? The domain $\mathbb{C}$  isn't compact.

2. If you have here tried to prove the contrapositive, then since $F^{-1}(\infty)$ is the whole domain $\mathbb{C}$, the restriction of the map is from an empty set to $\mathbb{C}$, which will make the restriction holomorphic vacuously.

3. By definition, if $f(z)=\infty$, then $f$ is said to be analytic at $z$ if $1/f(z)$ is analytic at $z=0$. And here $1/f(z)=1/\infty=0$ everywhere and hence analytic. Am I making some mistake by taking $1/\infty=0$?

The last line was really helpful!

Comment: 1. I don't know about the general case. I included a proof for this specific case. 2.3. As you say that, now I indeed think it's a matter of convention, and I'm not aware of the current standard convention in the domain.

Comment: Just the way removable singularities can be eliminated by altering the function, poles can be removed by extending the co-domain to Riemann sphere. Consequently, since the function $f(z)=\infty$ itself is not defined with co-domain $\mathbb{C}$ to start with (not defined anywhere, not even a function to be precise), we have no reason to eliminate its "isolated singularities" by trying to fix something. So, it can be a conventional issue, but ofc it would invite redundancy since holomorphic and meromorphic functions to $\mathbb{\hat{C}}$ would just differ by one element. Thanks for proof!